# How do I find the sum of $\frac{\cos(n)}{n!}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am having a hard time to calculate the sum of $$\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{\cos(n)}{n!}$$ I don't know how to approach this. Could you give any thints for this?

Comment: $\cos n = \operatorname{Re} ( \cos n + i\sin n)$

Comment: I'm surprised you're dealing with $ \cos n $ for integer $ n $ - usually arguments to cosine are either continuous or integer multiples of $ \pi $ - it's unusual, say, to run into $ \sin 1 $. Is this really the problem you meant to ask?

Comment: @QuantumFool, expressions such as $\sin n$ and $\cos n$ for $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ aren't that uncommon when dealing with infinite series in an academic setting.

Comment: @QuantumFool, expressions such as $\sin n$ and $\cos n$ for $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ aren't that uncommon when dealing with infinite series in an academic setting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum\frac{\cos n}{n!}& =\Re\sum\frac{e^{in}}{n!} \\
& = \Re e^{e^i}\\
& = e^{\cos 1} \cos(\sin 1)
\end{align}

Comment: nice solution! +1)

Comment: Short and clear! Perfect, thank you!