# Find the sum of the series $\frac{\sin(nx)}{n!}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Find the sum of the series using the Fourier series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{n!}$.  I think I should find a function that in the expansion in a Fourier series gives something similar on the formula above.

Comment: Hint:  $\sin (\sin (x)) (\sinh (\cos (x))+\cosh (\cos (x)))$.

Comment: Perhaps this is also helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984531/how-do-i-find-the-sum-of-frac-cosnn/1984539#1984539

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that $e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$ and $\sin(nx)=\text{Im}\left((e^{ix)})^n\right)$.  Now, let $z=e^{ix}$

Comment: and then $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{n!} =$ Im $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 
 \frac{e^{ix}}{n!}=$ Im $e^{e^z}$ and what is this?

Comment: I would have thought that the imaginary part was real...

Comment: $e^{\cos x} (cos(sin(x))+isin(sin(x))$ ?

Comment: Now, take the imaginary part.

Comment: $z=e^{ix}$.  Hence, we have $$\text{Im}\left(e^{e^{ix}}\right)=\text{Im}\left(e^{\cos(x)+i\sin(x)}\right)$$Can you finish now?

Comment: $e^{\cos x} sin(sin(x))$. Thanks a lot! nice solution

Comment: @user1223 You're welcome. My pleasure.